# Catch form submit not working

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms

I've been trying out several samples to catch a submit from a form but all I get is a reload of the page.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    var frm = $('#export-form');
    //Catch the submit
    frm.submit(function(ev) {
        console.log("Here I am")  //Not visible in Firebug
        // Prevent reload
        ev.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type        : 'POST', 
            url         : 'libs/GenerateCSV.php', 
            data        : 'export', 
            success     : function (data) {
                alert('success'); // Temporary debugging, later a redirection is planned
            }
        });
    });
});
```

But the script is never executed.
I've tried to use an onsubmit call but I had the same result.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are any error messages shown in the JavaScript console? (Make sure you set your console to persist messages across reloads so you can see them)

Comment: "later a redirection to a file is planned" — The point of Ajax is to update the content without loading a completely new file. If you're going to redirect anyway, why aren't you using a regular form submission?

Comment: I'm not getting any error messages, as far as I can see the code code is never executed.

What do you mean with regular form submission?
I have to call the php script first to generate the file and then I want to download it. My idea is to let the js code sleep for a short amount of time and then redirect to the stored file, to handle any kind of delays with mysql.

Comment: A regular form. You have a form. You have a submit button. You don't have any JavaScript.

Comment: If there are no error messages, then I don't see why that wouldn't work. (Assuming the code in the question accurately reflects the code you are testing)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try this approach

```
<!-- Include jQuery before this code -->
<form id="export-form" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <a id="submit-form" href="#">Start Download</a>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#submit-form").click(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type        : 'POST', 
                url         : 'libs/GenerateCSV.php', 
                data        : 'export',
                success     : function (data) {
                    alert('success');//Just for debugging, later a redirection to a file is planned 
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

anchor tag won't automatically submit your form and redirect you. I always use this solution to submit form without redirection. You can on success event redirect wherever you want. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing looks wrong in your code sample.

Did you make sure that jQuery is loaded before your script ?

Also, you can wrap your code in a `document.ready` statement:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    // your code goes here
});
```

Comment: The script is after the form. Using a ready handler won't make any difference.

Comment: I've tried both and added a console log in the frm submit but the site is still just reloading.

Answer (score 0):

Check your HTML code, I guess maybe you write `onClick` in `<input>`, like below:

```
<input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="this.form.submit(); this.disabled=true; this.value='waiting ...'; ">
```